# XMLHttRequest readystate not showing 4

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

Why i am always getting XMLHttpRequest readystate  not as 4 
i am also printing it in alert box it always show from 1,2,3
im running out of sequence please check and let me know any advice or suggestions are warmly welcome

```
var xmlHttp;
xmlHttp = CreateXMLHttpRequestObject();

function CreateXMLHttpRequestObject() {
    var isValidObj = true;

    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject();
        }
        catch (ex) {

            isValidObj = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch (ex) {

                isValidObj = false;
            }


        }
    }
    if (!isValidObj) {
        alert("Your browser do not support ajax");

    }
    return xmlHttp;

}

function Process() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 0 || xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {

        var food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('txtFood').value);
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "Default.aspx?food=" + food, true)
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.send();
    }

}
function handleServerResponse() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            var strResponse = xmlHttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("divResult").innerHTML = "<span style='color:blue'>" + strResponse + " </span>";
            setTimeout('process()', 1000)
        }
    }
    else {
        alert(xmlHttp.readyState);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should like this according to me no need of your process() function
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange event automatically call on each state change.

```
var food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('txtFood').value);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
       var strResponse = xmlHttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("divResult").innerHTML = "<span style='color:blue'>" + strResponse + " </span>";
  }
  else
  {
    alert(xmlHttp.readyState);
  }
}

xmlHttp.open("GET", "Default.aspx?food=" + food, true);
xmlHttp.send();
```

Comment: how can you use open method after the onreadystatechange event handler?